# Разработка на Golang под Android

Tags: android, golang, tablet

Хочу купить планшет и заодно использовать его для написания кода на Go в offline, есть ли какие-нибудь варианты IDE, и конечно чтобы была возможность запуска и тестирования кода.

Comment: Вот что-то похожее: https://androidinsider.ru/obzory-prilozhenij/dcoder-mobilnyiy-ide-dlya-programmistov.html

Comment: Ключевое слово offline, почти все эти IDE компилируют в облаке, и без сети по сути неработают.

Comment: Можно использовать android studio, но оно направлено на написание на языке Java, Kotlin. В нем есть визуальное представление экранов приложения. Так же можно использовать любою другую IDE для golang, список IDE https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/IDEsAndTextEditorPlugins
Есть либа для написание приложений для android https://github.com/golang/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

1. Установите приложение Termux через Play Market
2. Запустите Termux и в терминале наберите `apt-get update && apt-get install -y golang`
3. Дождитесь окончания установки
4. В качестве IDE можно использовать midnight commander, vim, etc. Для разделения экрана можно воспользоваться tmux или screen.

Для проверки введите `$ go version`

Получите вывод `go version go1.12.7 android/amd64`, версии могут отличаться в будущем.

Comment: Писать код в mc конечно ещё то удовольствие, но тоже как вариант

Comment: @pnp2000 в termux есть vim и emacs, так что жить можно.